# Function to generate nearly sorted numbers

Tags: python

I wrote function to generate nearly sorted numbers:

```
def nearly_sorted_numbers(n):
    if n >= 100:
        x = (int)(n/10)
    elif n >= 10:
        x = 9
    else:
        x = 4 
    numbers = []    
    for i in range(1,n):
        if i%x==0: 
            numbers.append(random.randint(0,n))
        else:
            numbers.append(i)
return numbers
```

Have you any idea how improve my code?

Comment: What's the purpose of this code?

Comment: I want to make performance test for sorting algorithms and this function should prepare input data according to x parameter (length of input data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def nearly_sorted_numbers(n):
    if n >= 100:
        x = (int)(n/10)
```

Use `int(n//10)`, the `//` explicitly request integer division and python doesn't have casts

```
    elif n >= 10:
        x = 9
    else:
        x = 4
```

I wouldn't name the variable `x`, as it gives no hint as to what it means. I'd also wonder whether it wouldn't be better as a parameter to this function. It seems out of place to be deciding that here.

```
    numbers = []    
    for i in range(1,n):
        if i%x==0: 
            numbers.append(random.randint(0,n))
        else:
            numbers.append(i)
return numbers
```